# Taylor series based on power series

Tags: taylor-expansion

Set up the Taylor series to $f (x) = \ln (1 + 2x)$ about$ x = 0 $ based on
the power series  $ \frac{1}{1-x}$
.
I have found that Taylor series of $f(x)$ is $2x-2x^2+\frac{8}{3}x^3-4x^4+...,$ but how do I base it on $\frac{1}{1-x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\ln(1+2x)=-\int_0^{-2x}\frac{1}{1-t}\,dt$$

Comment: So like this? $-\int _0^{-2x}\frac{1}{1-t}dt=-\int _0^{-2x}\left(1+t+t^2+...+t^n\right)dt=2x-2x^2+\frac{8}{3}x^3+...+\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\frac{2^n}{n!}x^n$

Comment: Yes, exactly, but don't forget that $-\int _0^{-2x}\left(1+t+t^2+...+t^n+\dots\right)dt$ (the dots after $t^n$)

Comment: Nice, thanks for help